# Power Bi non understandable Dax Formula

Tags: powerbi

i need a translation for this Dax Formula :

```
ACA = IF('Underpenetrated List'[ACR]>= 5000 && 
              LOOKUPVALUE('Underpenetrated List'[ACR],
                          'Underpenetrated List'[Date],
                          PREVIOUSMONTH('Underpenetrated List'[Date]),
                          'Underpenetrated List'[TPID],
                          'Underpenetrated List'[TPID]) <5000,
         1,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This calculation is checking the ACR value of the current month and ACR value of the previous month. This roughly translates to:

```
If ACR Value of the current month >= 5000
AND
If ACR Value of the Previous month < 5000
THEN 1 ELSE 0
```

Hope this helps.